# Common causes of - Access Violation errors under .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, access-violation

I'm looking for common causes of Access Violation errors under .NET.

Things I have checked so far -

- Call Dispose on all objects implementing IDisposable
- Check for valid arguments in calls to COM objects
- Explicitly remove all manually added event handlers
- DO NOT explicity call GC.Collect/GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers
- Add and *Remove* memory pressure when dealing with native objects (Bitmap, etc..) (**Added**)
- Verify all PInvoke calls for valid argument types
- Ensure proper use of IntPtr, SafeHandle and HandleRef
- Threading (Thread Safe, Reentrant functions), proper use of waithandles. (**Added**)
- Ensure application and DLL's are all targetting the same platform (x86 or x64) (The application and dll's should target the same platform as the COM objects.) (**Added**)

Any other suggestions?

**Edit** - Moved crash dump analysis to different question.

Comment: You should erase the part about capturing a dump and ask it as a new question. It's not really related to this one, except that you're currently trying to diagnose an error in your program.

Answer (score 3):

Any use of unsafe or unmanaged code can get you that type of exceptions.

[AccessViolationException:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx)

> An access violation occurs in
>   unmanaged or unsafe code when the code
>   attempts to read or write to memory
>   that has not been allocated, or to
>   which it does not have access. This
>   usually occurs because a pointer has a
>   bad value. Not all reads or writes
>   through bad pointers lead to access
>   violations, so an access violation
>   usually indicates that several reads
>   or writes have occurred through bad
>   pointers, and that memory might be
>   corrupted. Thus, access violations
>   almost always indicate serious
>   programming errors. In the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0, an
>   AccessViolationException clearly
>   identifies these serious errors.
>
> In programs consisting entirely of
>   verifiable managed code, all
>   references are either valid or null,
>   and access violations are impossible.
>   An AccessViolationException occurs
>   only when verifiable managed code
>   interacts with unmanaged code or with
>   unsafe managed code.

Recommended:

[GFlags](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738763.aspx) and [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948.aspx)

Comment: Yup, that defines it well.  Do you have suggestions as to what to look for in your .NET code to help prevent or track down these types of errors?

Comment: Hi, sure, Edited the answer to include those (GFlags and Application verifier)

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced a consistent access violation crash as a result of an infinite recursion in .NET 6.

Comment: I had a property getter in a wpf view model that was returning itself instead of the backing field.

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating IL at runtime or using a component which does so? Using unsafe C# code, doing pointer manipulation?

Comment: @SDX2000 - Good thinking.  Thanks for the suggestions.